# Creating a multipart form component with Redux, Thunk, Axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, multipartform-data, redux-thunk

I am trying to create the final stage of a multitype form that I have created in React. I think I am close to creating a handleSubmit method for posting my multipart form data to my backend database however I am getting the below erros messages relating to CORS issues.

Am I going about adding to my Redux store and my backend the right way? Do I need to add some sort of parser to my service "createDiveSpot" method to seperate the text, numbers and images? Do these error messages come me not having request headers?

error messages when rendering page

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

error on console
[image]

```
    // state for the current field value
    const [spot, setSpot] = useState({
        diveLocation: "",
        diveRegionID: "",
        diveTypeID: "",
        diveSpotDescription: "",
        diveSpotPhotos: "",
        error: ''
    });

    // all onChange functions do the exact same thing, so you only need one
    // pass to a component like onChange={handleChange('typeID')}
    const handleChange = (property) => (e) => {
        setSpot({
            // override the changed property and keep the rest
            ...spot,
            [property]: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    // get access to dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // useEffect with an empty dependency array is the same as componentDidMount
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(requireFieldData());
    }, []);

    const handleSubmitDiveSpot = () => {

        const diveSpot = {
            diveLocation: spot.diveLocation || undefined,
            diveRegionID: spot.diveRegionID || undefined,
            diveSpotTypeID: spot.diveSpotTypeID || undefined,
            diveSpotDescription: spot.diveSpotDescription || undefined,
            diveSpotPhotos: spot.diveSpotPhotos || undefined
        }

        // do some stuff with the form
        createDiveSpot(diveSpot).then((data) => {
            if (data.error) {
                setSpot({ ...spot, error: data.error})
            } else {
                setSpot({ ...spot, error: '', open: true})
            }
        })
        // do we need to save this to the backend? or just to redux?
        dispatch(addDiveSpot(spot));
        }

    const classes = useStyles;

    return (

        // <AppBar title="Enter your dive details"></AppBar>
        <form className="diveSpotForm" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={handleSubmitDiveSpot}>

            <>
                <Grid container spacing={3}
                      direction="row"
                      justify="center"
                      alignItems="center">
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                        <PopulateDropdown
                            dataList={diveTypeList}
                            titleProperty={"diveType"} // option label property
                            valueProperty={"diveTypeID"} // option value property
                            name="diveType"
                            placeholder="Dive Type"
                            label="Select Dive Type"
                            value={spot.diveTypeID}
                            onChange={handleChange("diveTypeID")}/>
                    </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <br />
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                            <PopulateDropdown
                                dataList={regionList}
                                titleProperty={"diveRegion"} // option label property
                                valueProperty={"diveRegionID"} // option value property
                                name="diveRegion"
                                placeholder="Dive Region"
                                label="Select Region"
                                value={spot.diveRegionID}
                                onChange={handleChange("regionID")}/>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <br />
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                        <TextField
                            label="diveLocation"
                            placeholder="Dive Location"
                            name="diveLocation"
                            margin="normal"
                            value={spot.diveLocation}
                            onChange={handleSubmitDiveSpot("diveLocation")}/>
                    </Grid>
                    <br />
                    <Grid item xs={10}>
                        <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.margin}>
                            <TextField
                                label="Description"
                                name="diveSpotDescription"
                                value={spot.diveSpotDescription}
                                onChange={handleSubmitDiveSpot("diveSpotDescription")}
                                multiline
                                rowsMax={6}/>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <br />
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.margin}>
                            <label for="photos">Photo Upload</label>
                            <input
                                type="file"
                                name="photo"
                                value={spot.diveSpotPhotos}
                                onChange={handleSubmitDiveSpot("diveSpotPhotos")}/>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <br />
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                            Submit</Button>
                        <br />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </>
        </form>
```

Comment: The message is `404 Not Found` -- are you sure that `/api/divespots/createdivespot` is the correct URL?  And that your backend can handle it?  Usually it would be just one path like `/api/divespots` and you would use a `PUT` or `POST` request type to denote that you are creating an item, vs `GET` to read data.  [HTTP Request Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Comment: Some of the inputs have the wrong `onChange` function.  You have `handleSubmitDiveSpot("diveLocation")` but it should be `handleChange("diveLocation")`.  That's the reason for the "too many re-renders".

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you need to change the way you have the onChange prop set up.

Instead of:

```js
onChange={handleChange("diveTypeID")}
```

you should have this:

```js
onChange={(event, id) => handleChange(event, "diveTypeID"}
```

- [React onChange Events](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onchange-events-with-examples)
- [React - Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem starts with how you provide the handler to `onChange`. If you call a function on render, instead pass a reference of the function, you will have that problem with exceeding the nested update.

Maybe, try to change `onChange={handleChange("diveTypeID")}` to something `onChange={(e)=> handleChange(e,"diveTypeID")}` or `onChange={handleChange.bid(this,"diveTypeID")}`

Comment: The `handleChange` is a curried function `const handleChange = (property) => (e) => ` so it's ok to use `onChange={handleChange("diveTypeID")}` because that creates an event handler (I wrote that function for him on another question lol).  `handleSubmitDiveSpot` is **not** a curried function so what you are saying is correct in regards to `handleSubmitDiveSpot`.